# For each or Named Range to populate ListBox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

All I am trying to populate a listbox with a For Each loop which iterates through the rows. The for each loop is going through the items in a Named range (ProgramIDs).

The current code I am using is

```
If Len(ProjectInformation.Range("H2").Value) = 7 Then

    Dim Lr As Long
    Lr = Range("H1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each C In Range("H2:H" & Lr)
        With Program_ListBox
            .AddItem C.Value
        End With
    Next C

End If
```

I fear this is a very basic question however after researching the website / google I simply cannot get this simple task to function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `ProjectInformation` a worksheet or the named range?  If it is a range are you sure the `H` is referring to the correct column.  For example `Range("B:B").Range("H2")` refers to `Range("I2")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range("H2:H" & Lr)` references the cells on the `ActiveSheet`.  You should always fully qualify your references.

```
With ProjectInformation
    If Len(.Range("H2").Value) = 7 Then
        For Each C In .Range("H2", .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            With Program_ListBox
                .AddItem C.Value
            End With
        Next C
    End If
End With
```

There is no need loop the cells to the add the values to the listbox.  You can assign the `Range().Value` array directly to the `Listbox.List` array.

```
 With ProjectInformation
    If Len(.Range("H2").Value) = 7 Then
        Program_ListBox.List = .Range("H2", .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you very much for your time, the explanation is much appreciated as well!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop, you can pass the range as the source of the listbox

```
Program_ListBox.List = Range("H2:H" & Lr)
```